# "She is sneezing again so i think she has cold". is this a correct sentence?

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

I wrote this sentence and my teacher punished me for that. he said that the correct sentence would be "she is sneezing again so I think she has had a cold".
I searched it online but didnt get any satisfactory answer.
i just want to know which is correct sentence and why?

Comment: When we are suffering from the common cold, we say we have `a cold`. You need the indefinite article.

Comment: _She has had a cold_ would mean that she has recently recovered from one.

Comment: You are supposed to indicate which part of the sentence you think is wrong, and why, otherwise it becomes proofreading which is off-topic.

Comment: Your teacher punished you??

Comment: Thank you so much for solving my doubt. My teacher told me that "She has had a cold would be the correct sentence". I know it is "a cold" rather than "cold". It was a typing mistake. but thank you all for your answers. I am truly grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Neither version is correct. You would say:

> She is sneezing again so I think she **has a cold.**

Since she is sneezing now, she still has a cold now, so you would say "has," not "has had."

Since "cold" is a count noun in this sense, you would say "a cold," not just "cold."

Comment: Is it possible to put in the Present Perfect with "to catch": "She is sneezing again so I think she has caught cold."? And why is no indefinite article needed in this case?